# Bufferoverflow error on doing HttpClient GET android

Tags: android, httpclient

I am trying to get resources from remote site using HttpClient in android. I have been trying the following

```
public class Engine {

    public String test(){
        String engineUrl = "http://site/path"; //I used legit site and path here
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet req = new HttpGet(engineUrl);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(req);  <<----this
            //is = response.getEntity().getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("error", "err");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

wheneverI try to execute the given tagged method, I get an error. If I dont execute .execute() method, everything works fine.

My calling fragment is:

```
public class mainFragment extends Fragment{
    View view = null;
    Context context = null;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
         context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();

         final TextView v = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.hello);

         Thread t = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Engine e = new Engine();
                v.setText(e.test());

            }

         };
         t.run();

         return view;
    }

}
```

Thanks anyway!!

Thanks everybody, I think I solved the problem. I have to use AsyncTask<> for network operations not thread class. Thanks again

Comment: How big are the resources you try to download? For big downloads I'd recommend using the DownloadManager: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

Comment: its quite small, just about 100-150 ascii letters

Comment: Oh okay, and the BufferOverflowException is thrown exactly at the line of the  httpclient.execute(req) ? Or somewhere else?

Comment: yea! when I comment it out, it works fine. Just on the httpclient.execute(req)

Comment: I used permission INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. I hope,they are adequate to perform this operation?

Comment: Yes, they are adequate. Could you please add the stacktrace to your post?

Comment: I tried using HttpURLConnection, but it also generates exception whenever at .getReponseCode() method of HttpURLConnection..

Comment: at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)

Comment: I pulled those out of logcat

Comment: Please, add the whole stacktrace. Just this little bit doesn't really help.

Comment: How can I get whole stacktrace from logcat. Console really doesnt showup anything in adt

Comment: Just copy them from logcat, or mark the lines and then export them to file and copy them after that.

Comment: I got those lines by doing so. Logcat shows no more contents than that

Comment: I tried AsyncTask and now it works, Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call

```
v.setText(e.test())
```

in

```
run().
```

As UI changes have to be done in the UI thread. Try with

```
final String result = e.test():

runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
private void run (){
v.setText(result);
}
}).
```